# How do I set the color of quick reply text in Gifted Chat?

Tags: react-native-gifted-chat

I see how to set the styles of quick reply options in [React Native Gifted Chat](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat) using `quickReplyStyle`, but no styles set there seem to have any effect on the color of the quick reply text itself.

How do I set the color of quick reply text in Gifted Chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text color is a property on the `QuickReplies` component [[source](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/c1e51b0d92e3ba4adf32712844c69e059b6b62aa/src/QuickReplies.tsx)], so you'll need to change it in the `renderQuickReplies` property like so:

```
<GiftedChat
    ...
    renderQuickReplies={(props) => <QuickReplies color='red' {...props} />}
    ...
/>
```

Note: the text will always be `white` when the quick reply is selected.

You may need to add the import for `QuickReplies` like so:

```
import QuickReplies from 'react-native-gifted-chat/lib/QuickReplies';
```

Helpful, related issue [here](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/672).

Comment: That gives _"Error TS2693: 'QuickReplies' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here"_ in code inspection; and _"Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined, You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports"_ when I try to run it.

Comment: Hmmm...does adding the import statement help?

Comment: That works. I couldn't get the import right before. Any idea how to control other aspects of the text (e.g. make it bold)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's a way to do that.  It'd need to be set on the `Text` element [here](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/blob/c1e51b0d92e3ba4adf32712844c69e059b6b62aa/src/QuickReplies.tsx#L189).